# How to check if PostgreSQL public schema exists?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

Running the following query:

```
SELECT exists (
    SELECT
        schema_name 
    FROM
        information_schema.schemata 
    WHERE
        schema_name = 'public'
) AS schema_exists;
```

I am getting always `FALSE`, even if the public schema exists.

How should i check if this schema exists?

**EDIT**

I am using PostgreSQL version 8.4

Comment: It returns true (as a boolean value) for me when I run it locally... How are you checking for the return value?

Comment: How do you know that public schema exists ? i'm executing the same query and getting true !

Comment: @Ruslan, I am using PostgreSQL 8.4. What is your version?

Comment: @Houari, I am using PostgreSQL 8.4. What is your version?

Comment: Have you tried to run `SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata ` to check all schema that are present?

Comment: @MarcioSimao My version is 9.2.1, could you please update your question by adding your `PostgreSQL` version ?

Comment: @MarcioSimao Sorry, I'm on 9.3.1

Comment: I guess you can also try SELECT exists(select 1 from pg_namespace where nspname = 'public') as schema_exists;

Comment: @SaUce, Yes, i tried, but i get an empty result

Comment: @Houari, I updated just now, thanks

Comment: in that case your query is correct and it would never return true. Are you sure you are executing this on correct database and does your user have required permission to read it?

Comment: @Ruslan, Using `SELECT exists(select 1 from pg_namespace where nspname = 'public')` i finally got `TRUE`. Please post you comment as an answer. Do you know the difference between `information_schema.schemata` and `pg_namespace`?

Comment: @SaUce, Yes, i am sure. Running the query that @Ruslan said i got `TRUE`. Now i am trying to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information from `information_schema.schemata` depends on the role you're connected with, so it's not really the right view to query to discover schemas in general.

The [doc on `information_schema.schemata` in 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/infoschema-schemata.html) says:

> The view schemata contains all schemas in the current database that
>   are owned by a currently enabled role.

However it's not quite clear (at least to me) from just that sentence, why you can't see `public` .

In a mailing-list post, Tom Lane has an explanation the goes a bit further:
See http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/11650.1357782995@sss.pgh.pa.us

His conclusion:

> As things stand, a non-superuser won't see "public", "pg_catalog", nor
>   even "information_schema" itself in this view, which seems a tad
>   silly.

which looks exactly like the problem in this question.

Bottom line: use `pg_namespace` instead of `information_schema.schemata`

---

This was amended in version 9.4  to conform to what users expect. The [current doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-schemata.html) says:

> The view schemata contains all schemas in the current database that
>   the current user has access to (by way of being the owner or having
>   some privilege).

`USAGE` privilege on a schema is now enough to get it from this view.

Comment: Very rich your answer, many thanks! I am going to use `pg_namespace ` instead of `information_schema.schemata`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can't see public schema because of the database role you are using to test schema existence. `information_schema.schemata` is actually a view with the following definition:

```
 SELECT 
    current_database()::information_schema.sql_identifier AS catalog_name,
    n.nspname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS schema_name,
    u.rolname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS schema_owner, 
    NULL::character varying::information_schema.sql_identifier AS default_character_set_catalog,
    NULL::character varying::information_schema.sql_identifier AS default_character_set_schema,
    NULL::character varying::information_schema.sql_identifier AS default_character_set_name,
    NULL::character varying::information_schema.character_data AS sql_path
   FROM pg_namespace n, pg_authid u
  WHERE n.nspowner = u.oid AND pg_has_role(n.nspowner, 'USAGE'::text);
```

This is also described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-schemata.html).

You can get the definition of views in `information_schema` using `\d+` in psql - `\d+ information_schema.schemata` in this case.

You should use `pg_namespace` instead of `information_schema.schemata`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you know what is the best workaround for this?

Comment: Use `pg_namespace` instead as described in answer by Ruslan.

Answer (score 1):

That query that you wrote should have worked... Try this alternative:

```
select count(*) > 0 FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'public';
```

Comment: I still receive `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

(Posting as an answer from comments)

Referencing the pg_namespace table directly might be a decent workaround...

```
SELECT exists(select 1 from pg_namespace where nspname = 'public') as schema_exists;
```

I don't know what the exact differences are, but do know that namespaces "back" schemas internally in PostgreSQL.

Also, I believe those system pg_* tables are not *guaranteed* to stay consistent across versions, but it has been there since at least 7.3 (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html) and is there now (9.3.1).