# Jooq not able to find my public schemas from database

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to programatically generate code using jooq 3.12.3 with the following code, but the program runs successfully and no code is generated.

```
  Configuration configuration =
      new Configuration()
          .withJdbc(
              new Jdbc()
                  .withDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
                  .withUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6666/postgres")
                  .withUser("<username>")
                  .withPassword("<correct password>"))
          .withGenerator(
              new Generator()
                  .withDatabase(
                      new Database()
                          .withName("org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase")
                          .withIncludes(".*")
                          .withExcludes("")
                          .withInputSchema("public"))

                  .withGenerate(
                      new Generate()
                          .withDaos(true)
                          .withDeprecated(false)
                          .withImmutablePojos(false)
                          .withPojosEqualsAndHashCode(true)
                          .withValidationAnnotations(true)
                          .withVarargSetters(false))
                  .withTarget(
                      new Target()
                          .withPackageName("com.package.data.jooq")
                          .withDirectory("src/main/java")));
  GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
```

Some debugging info

```
\dt
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |  Owner
--------+-------------------+-------+----------
 public | django_migrations | table | postgres
 public | table1            | table | postgres
 public | table2            | table | postgres
```

,

```
\l
                                                List of databases
     Name      |       Owner       | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |            Access privileges
---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------
 cloudsqladmin | cloudsqladmin     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |
 postgres      | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |
```

,

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

**doesn't show public under table_schema**
What could be the problem?

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using? There used to be an issue where tables weren't listed by the `information_schema`, when no active role owns the objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21783658/521799

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks! The version is 9.6.15..
I solved it by giving access to the role. See the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks for documenting your solution here!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with permissions..

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.table1 TO user;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.table2 TO user;
```

Solved the problem. After this the tables started showing up in

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO your_user;`